# Within a node, how can I reference the value of a field of a node associated to the current user through a node-reference?

Tags: views, entities, nodes

I'm creating a customer extranet for my client. The users are my client's customers. Within the body of a page node, I need to display the ID of the customer (company) to which the current user belongs.

Here's how I've set it up so far:

- Drupal 7
- I have a Customer content type that has a field called customer_id (among other things).
- I have added a node-reference field to the User fields that references one Customer node. (In other words, each user is associated with one Customer.)

So in his profile, the current user has a node-reference value pointing to a Customer node, and I need to retrieve and display (in a page node or block) the value of one field (customer_id) in the Customer node being referenced in the current user's profile.

I've been going through several Drupal books and whatever module documentation I can find, and I've been experimenting with various views using the the Views module, but I'm still pretty stymied. Can somebody point me in the direction of a good way to implement this?

Thank you for your help!

Chris

Comment: Will anybody respond to this? Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this through Views arguments, with the nid of the customer node as the argument. Then that node's fields should be available to you from there.